# Routing non restfull controller with subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Ok Im building an API and I need the routes so I can access them like this:

api.example.com/action

or

api.example.com/action2

those are non-restful actions on my API controller:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  def action1
    #code
  end

  def action2
    #code
  end
end
```

how can I route them, any pointers?

Comment: It would be much easier to achieve that by doing `example.com/api/action`.  Something we do at work is `domain.com/api/v1/...` as that allows us to do versioning on our API as well.

Comment: its a requirement for it to be in its own subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want both `www.domain.com` and `api.domain.com` will point to the same rails app.

In your routes file you're going to need to setup a constraint to only perform a set of routes when that constraint is true.  The constraint you're going to want to use will simply check to see if the subdomain of the current request is `'api'`.  This can be achieved by the following code segment:

**config/routes.rb:**

```
constraints subdomain: 'api' do
  # Standard Routing
  match '/action1' => 'api#action1'

  # Wildcard Routing
  match '/:action" => 'api#%{action}'
end
```

**Request Constraints:**
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

**Wildcard Segments**:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments

Comment: and is there a way for them to be wildcard actions something like this: match '/*' => 'api#*'

Comment: Couldn't you do `match '/:action" => 'api#%{action}'`?